# Difference between ' and ` on the linux terminal (zsh shell)

Tags: shell, zsh

Using ' and ` leads to different results when setting a variable on the zsh shell script -

```
>>>one=`echo test`
>>>$one
>>>
>>>two='echo test'
>>>$two
>>>zsh: command not found: echo test
```

What the are the functions of the two?

Comment: backticks are used (not POSIX) to run commands.

Comment: Here's zsh documentation: [quotes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Quoting), [backticks](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution). Also see [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) for why it's better to ask a single question per post.

Comment: @Tico see [POSIX Shell 2.6.3 Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)

Answer (score 1):

This is not as simple as it may seem. Here is a *shallow* explanation of what is happening. Depending on the shell (and version), variables such as `IFS` and other possibilities including at least aliases, any or all of the below may not apply, but I think it's a reasonable way of thinking about it in the normal case. Since I'm more familiar with Bash than Zsh I've included Bash references, but all this *should* apply to Zsh and other POSIX-ish shells as well.

Let's deconstruct these line by line.

`` one=`echo test` ``:

1. Since the line starts with a valid variable name followed by an equals sign, it is a **variable assignment**, so the right side is processed first.
2. `` `echo test` `` is a [**command substitution**](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution). (In modern shells this form is [discouraged](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution#Portability) in favour of `$(echo test)`.) This is processed as follows:

   1. The string inside the backticks (`echo test`) is [word split](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) into “echo” and “test”.
   2. The command consisting of the command “echo” is *executed* with an argument list consisting of a single item “test”. This is a rabbit hole, and I don't know the details, so I won't even try to explain what happens to actually execute this command. I think it has to do with `execve`?

      1. Standard error (in this case nothing) of the command is sent to the terminal as usual.
      2. Standard *output* of the command (in this case and this order, the bytes corresponding to the [Basic Latin](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/basic-latin/) characters “t”, “e”, “s”, “t” and a [newline](https://unicode-table.com/en/000A/)) are then *right trimmed* of newlines, ending up with the bytes 0x74, 0x65, 0x73 and 0x74.
3. The bytes above are assigned to the variable `one`.

`$one`:

1. This is a **variable substitution**. The bytes above are substituted for the variable, and the resulting string is treated as a command.
2. `test` is indeed a command (and very likely a zsh built-in as well), so it runs fine and returns with an exit code of 1 because there were no arguments. See `help test` or `man test` for an in-depth explanation.

`two='echo test'`:

1. Same as the other assignment, except the right side is a **single [quoted](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) string**. This means the entire contents between the two [apostrophes](https://unicode-table.com/en/0027/) is considered as a single *literal string*, and no word splitting occurs in it.
2. The resulting set of bytes corresponding to the string “echo test” is assigned to the variable `two`.

`$two`:

1. Like the other variable expansion, the *entire string* is treated as a command, because no word splitting happens before executing it. It would indeed be possible to create a command “echo test” (for example using `ln -s /bin/echo '/bin/echo test'`)
2. Since the command does not exist on your system (and indeed, on any other sane *nix system), `zsh` helpfully prints an error message to this effect.